# MySQL is not receiving information. Using MySQLi extension

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

```
    <?php
    include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
    if($user_ok != true){
           header("location: login.php");
        exit();
        }
    ?>
    <?php
            $id = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$log_username'";
    if(isset($_POST["signupbtn"])) {
        if ($log_username) {
            /// getting data from submitted form into local variables
            $x = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]#i', '', $_POST['xbox']);
            $p  = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]#i', '', $_POST['psn']);
            $s = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]#i', '', $_POST['steam']);
            $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
            // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR GAMER PROFILES
            $sqli = "SELECT username FROM player WHERE xbox='$x' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli); 
            $x_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            // -------------------------------------------
            if ($x_check > 0){ 
                echo "Xbox Gamer-Tag already linked to a user on this website";
                exit();
            } else if (is_numeric($x[0])) {
                echo 'Xbox Gamer-Tag cannot begin with a number';
                exit();
            }
            $sqli = "SELECT username FROM player WHERE psn='$p' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli); 
            $p_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            // -------------------------------------------
             if ($p_check > 0){ 
                echo "PSN User already linked to a user on this website";
                exit();
            } else if (is_numeric($p[0])) {
                echo 'PSN User cannot begin with a number';
                exit();
            }
            $sqli = "SELECT username FROM player WHERE steam='$s' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli); 
            $s_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
             if ($s_check > 0){ 
                echo "Steam account already linked to a user on this website";
                exit();
            } else if (is_numeric($s[0])) {
                echo 'Steam account cannot begin with a number';
                exit();
            } else  { $sqli = "INSERT INTO player (id, username, xbox, psn, steam, ip, created, lastupdated, notecheck)        
                    VALUES ('$id','$log_username','$x','$p','$s','$ip',NOW(),NOW(),NOW())"; 
                    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli);
            }
                      echo "Gamer Profiles Updated";
            exit();

                if (!file_exists("p_player/$log_username")) {
                    mkdir("p_player/$log_username", 0755);
                } 


         }


    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/default/style/style.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    #profiles{
        margin-top:24px;    
    }
    #profiles > div {
        margin-top: 12px;   
    }
    #profiles > input,select {
        width: 200px;
        padding: 3px;
        background: #F3F9DD;
    }
    #profiles {
        font-size:18px;
        padding: 12px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include_once("templates/default/template_pageTop.php"); ?>
    <div id="pageMiddle">

 <h3>Gamer Profiles</h3>
  <form action="player.php" method="POST" name="profiles">
<div>Xbox Gamer-tag: <input type="text" name="xbox"></div>
<div>PSN User: <input type="text" name="psn"></div>
<div>Steam User: <input type="text" name="steam"></div>
<input type="submit" name="signupbtn">
</form>



</div>


<?php include_once("templates/default/template_pageBottom.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The $log_username variable comes from the top php script and every thing is fine with it as I can echo the variable and comes back with the logged user on this page.

so basicaly nothing is being written to my database on submitting the button and I am really stumped with it tbh. I am using the MySQLi extension within php 5 as I have been following a tutorial on things and have came to the end of the tutorial and now I am by myself. I was going to included a shot of my database below to prove that the names on the database is fine but with the fact that my rep is 9 I can't add one to make your lives easier as you need to b 10.

have I got a } in the wrong place or labeling something MySQL when it should be MySQLi.
When I submit the form the mkdir is made in the folder and I get sent to the page with the echo "Gamer Profiles Updated"

Thank you to anyone who tries to solve this problem out I have.

I have been trying to do this for hours tbh and from what i have done everything checks fine and it should be working in theory but it just doesn't work. Thank you once again for looking at this and I look forward to your responses.

Comment: Try moving the `echo "Gamer Profiles Updated";` into the block where you actually do the insert, just to be sure that code is being executed.

Comment: Check the return value from `mysqli_query`. If it's false, print `mysqli_error($db_conx)` to see the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just put it directly below the insert and within the }. It still comes back fine and sends me to echo page. Thank you for your reply

Comment: You're never calling `mysqli_query($id)` to get the ID, you're putting the `$id` SQL into the `INSERT` query. That's resulting in extra quotes and a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys but the response below solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$id = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$log_username'";
```

to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$log_username'") or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or die ("$log_username not found");
$id = $row['id'];
```

Comment: Dude you are a legend. I could actually kiss you. Thank you so much sir thank you so much.